# Код не запускается

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Столкнулся с проблемой - при запуске кода...

```cs
using System;

namespace Projectone   
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

...получаю ошибку...

```
[Running] scriptcs "d:\c#\test.cs"
'scriptcs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.      
[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.082 seconds
```

---

Редактор: Visual Studio Code

Comment: У вас консольное приложение?

Comment: Да, консольное.

Comment: Насколько я знаю консольном приложении должен быть класс `Program` с функцией `Main`

Comment: Хотя - нет. Только что проверил, класс `Program` не обязательно

Comment: А где вы компилируете? У меня всё [отлично работает](http://prntscr.com/sstlx4)

Comment: Как я уже говорил программа Visual Studio code, в ней и компилирую.

Comment: Откуда взялся этот `'scriptcs'`? Как вы создавали приложение? По шаблону или вручную?

Comment: Вручную, откуда scripts я не знаю.

Comment: Я вот в толк никак не могу взять, зачем самому себе с порога создавать проблемы? Почему не использовать `dotnet new console`?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code

Comment: сделайте класс паблик!

Comment: Очевидно вы установили в VS Code какое-то расширение для работы со скриптами (возможно, [scriptcsRunner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=filipw.scriptcsRunner)). А вам нужно расширение для [C#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp).

Comment: Также смотрите документацию: [Working with C#](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp)